# Android: Issue using JSON library in pure java package

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, gson

Our Android app has a package that consists of only pure Java code that is decoupled from Android. I need to use JSON in this package, and tried importing the [official JSON library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json). Whilst the import is successful, and I can use JSON in code, it refuses to work. I constantly get the same exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method g(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lorg/json/JSONObject; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.json.JSONObject' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

```
No virtual method b()Z in class Lorg/json/JSONObject; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.json.JSONObject' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this. I've read around that this is due to a conflict with Android's included JSON library but this is only being used in the pure Java library and any code interaction with Android involves strings or longs, not JSON

Has anyone ever experienced this? Or have any suggestions as to how I can use JSON in this pure java package?

I've tried importing a very old version of the JSON library incase it is due to some kind of conflict where I am using newer methods, but no dice. Same error. Also tried importing the jar instead of using gradle.

This is used for simple getter and setters for a database in ORMLITE. Here is one example where mExtraFlag is a string. Methods that also cause issues are toString from JSONObject and also the methods: valueToString, StringToValue etc...

```
public JSONObject getExtraFlag() {
 return new JSONObject(mExtraFlag);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who ever experiences the same issue, this is my hack fix. I decided to use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Again, I have to emphasize that this is for a **DECOUPLED JAVA PACKAGE**. **If you are attempting to import the JSON library in a regular Android package, this is probably not the solution for you.** Actually, the other answer might apply to you then.

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Maven:

```
<dependencies>
<!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Example parsing to json object and from a string

```
public JsonObject toJson(String value) {
    return new JsonParser().parse(value).getAsJsonObject();
}

// (probably dosen't require a method)
public String fromJson(JsonObject json) {
    return json.toString();
}
```

How to create and insert into a JSON object:

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
object.addProperty(key, value);
```

Example getting a long value (mExtraFlag is a string)

```
toJson(mExtraFlag).get(key).getAsLong();
```

Comment: Gson is always a Good solution also you can use Jackson. I save this solution for the future :)

Comment: whatever works I guess but it sucks that I have to use it for simple functionality :( i really only need it for jsonobjects. Jackson could also be a good idea

Answer (score 6):

I guess that the exception is thrown for your **obfuscated** builds, (since `g(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;` is obviously obfuscated).

As you have correctly mentioned, some java libs like `org.json` are already provided by android. This is especially an issue if one of your components want to use a different (e.g. newer) version of a specific lib, however android would simply replace your import by the version which is provided by android and as a consequence, `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` may be thrown if you call methods which are only available in the newer version. Usually, a solution to this issue is to shade the package name, so that it is not replaced.

However, a wrong version of `org.json` does not seem to be an issue in your case. The error is thrown because your `org.json` package was obfuscated in your build and the obfuscated method `g(...)` can of course not be found in android's `../core-libart.jar`.

You may have several options to resolve this issue:

- If your decoupled java package is used from a `.jar` import, it is obviously not handled as a transitive dependency, so as a consequence, `org.json` will get handled as a different lib than the one which is used by android, so `org.json` will get obfuscated. Therefore, you could add a proguard keep rule like:

```
-keep class org.json.**
-keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class org.json.** { *; }
```

- You could try to resolve the issue by handling your lib as a transitive dependency.
- You can try to shade `org.json` in your decoupled component, but imo this is not necessary and in the end it would only result in importing the same lib twice.

Imho, adding another lib like `gson` might not be necessary.